# Как включить категории в выдачу поиска WordPress (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, мне нужно выводить категории в поисковой выдачи...
То есть, например, посетитель ищет "батарейки", у нас есть категория "батарейки" и продукты, как в начале поисковой выдачи вывести категорию, а потом уже все остальное по стандарту?

Comment: Причем здесь order by? Мне нужно вывести категорию, а не отсортировать по категории.

Comment: @Akina можно попросить не лезть в темы ВП и не вводить людей в заблуждения? Спасибо.

Comment: @IlyaFrolov не понятно где нужно "выводить" - в поисковой выдаче гуглоаняндексов или в результатах поиска на сайте? Если первое, то просто не надо запрещать индексирование, а если второе... то это абсурд - категории не имеют собственного контента.

Comment: @SeVlad Да запросто.

Comment: @SeVlad При поиске на сайте. В моем случае категории имеют: название, описание, миниатюру. Например: имеется категория "батарейки" и товары...
Посетитель вводит на сайте: "батарейки"... Ему в выдаче показывается сначала категория "батарейки" (изображение, название, краткое описание), а потом уже все остальное.

Comment: Ты всерьёз полагаешь, что юзер приходит читать  (и ищет!) описание категории? Видимо не только я считаю это абсуром раз этого нет ни в движке ни в WC даже на уровне АПИ.  (кроме того это доп. нагрузка) Но нет ничего невозможного - надо написать плагин, в котором через [wpdb](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/)  будет искаться и в описаниях таксономий WC и в теле постов (товаров). Это разные поля таблиц.

Comment: @SeVlad В моем случае юзер ищет категории, чтобы посмотреть какие товары есть там! Так как страница категории выводит список товаров (а не карточки как стандарт)! У меня не стандартный сайт из коробки, и я не считаю это "абсурдом"! Спасибо за wpdb, я уже сделал прямым запросом в базу. И если этого нет в движке это не значит, что нужно отказываться от разработки.. WordPress очень гибок и можно делать все что угодно.

Answer (score 2):

В search.php добавьте еще 1 выборку по WP_Term_Query. Например:

```
$terms = WP_Term_Query( [
    's' => $_GET['s'] ?? '',
] );
var_dump( $terms );
```